# Which SQLite query performs better?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I've heard someone said that turning `case_sensitive_like` on can make the query work faster. If so, what do you think if we have 2 of the following queries which selects data on a case-insensitive like:

1. `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%Value%'`

   Suppose `case_sensitive_like` is off (by default), this will return the same result no matter `Value` is `value`, `vAlue`, `valUE`,...
2. `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = ON;`
   `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LOWER(MyColumn) LIKE LOWER('%Value%');`

   This will also return the same result no matter `Value` is `value`, `vAlue`, `valUE`, ...

I hope the #2 outperforms the #1.

Please help. Thanks.

PS: I think the performance for the #2 can be improved by declaring a constant for the Value first with value of lowercase string or this can be processed (for example in C# code) before passing in the query.

Comment: Of course, not yet, I think to try it, we have to prepare a huge data and have some experience on benchmark, but I'm not so experienced. I hope someone here tests it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that case sensitive searching does offer better performance but any benefit is mitigated by using the `LOWER` function. If you are worried about performance, use case sensitivity and ensure all the data is inserted in lower case. Or, better still, redesign to avoid the use of LIKE, especially LIKE with wildcards altogether.

Comment: Any operation in the WHERE clause (that's not a simple calculation or comparison) is relatively slow.

Comment: Thank you Jodrell and Rudie, you are right, in such case the #2 won't use lower function and it should outperform the #1. :)

Comment: If you really need to search text for words, and you need good performance on large datasets, like, for instance, here on StackOverflow, you'll need a different approach. Full-Text Searching in MS SQL and Lucene indexing spring to mind.

Comment: Thanks, I've heard of Full-text searching but I have only handled with small data which doesn't require speed. I have certainly to try it when there is a need. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect query number 2 to be slightly slower.

Like with "case_sensitive_like" turned off is effectively "LIKE LOWER(%...%)" but implemented within the LIKE function -- so option 1 is functionally the same but without the extra overhead of calling a separate function.

However as most of the time and resources will be spent hauling the data off the disk and locating "MyColumn" in the row I doubt if the difference would be noticeable.

Comment: And #2 will be __much__ slower if `MyColumn` is indexed :-)

Comment: On a large table, number 2 will be much slower.